# Calculate average execution time of a program using Bash

Tags: bash, time, execution

To get the execution time of any executable, say `a.out`, I can simply write `time ./a.out`. This will output a real time, user time and system time.

Is it possible write a bash script that runs the program numerous times and calculates and outputs the average real execution time?

Comment: The only caveat to be aware of is depending on how much of your code remains in cache, you subsequent runs will be artificially faster due to the cache.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could write a loop and collect the output of `time` command and pipe it to `awk` to compute the average:

```
avg_time() {
    #
    # usage: avg_time n command ...
    #
    n=$1; shift
    (($# > 0)) || return                   # bail if no command given
    for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do
        { time -p "$@" &>/dev/null; } 2>&1 # ignore the output of the command
                                           # but collect time's output in stdout
    done | awk '
        /real/ { real = real + $2; nr++ }
        /user/ { user = user + $2; nu++ }
        /sys/  { sys  = sys  + $2; ns++}
        END    {
                 if (nr>0) printf("real %f\n", real/nr);
                 if (nu>0) printf("user %f\n", user/nu);
                 if (ns>0) printf("sys %f\n",  sys/ns)
               }'
}
```

Example:

```
avg_time 5 sleep 1
```

would give you

```
real 1.000000
user 0.000000
sys 0.000000
```

This can be easily enhanced to:

- sleep for a given amount of time between executions
- sleep for a random time (within a certain range) between executions

---

Meaning of `time -p` from `man time`:

> ```
>    -p
>       When in the POSIX locale, use the precise traditional format
>
>       "real %f\nuser %f\nsys %f\n"
>
>       (with  numbers  in seconds) where the number of decimals in the
>       output for %f is unspecified but is sufficient to express the
>       clock tick accuracy, and at least one.
> ```

---

You may want to check out this command-line benchmarking tool as well:

[sharkdp/hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine)

Comment: Your approach causes the error `awk: division by zero` when I pass in the actual program as the argument, I think this error may be caused by rounding errors since the execution time of my program is very small.

Comment: Please use the updated answer and see if that works.  Also, show me your command.

Comment: I believe that the program works correctly now. A single arbitrary run with `time` gave `real 0m0.121s` while running the script gave `real 0.105000`. The command I used to execute the script on my program was `avg_time 10 ./a.out`.

Comment: Care! dividing sum of N rounded execution time is imprecise, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940448/1765658)

Comment: Try this: `avg_time 1000 sleep .001` !!

Comment: Why are you using both `&>` _and_ `2>&1`?

Answer (score 4):

## Total execution time vs sum of single execution time

**Care!** dividing sum of N rounded ***execution time*** is imprecise!

Instead, we could ***divide total execution time of N iteration*** (by N)

```
avg_time_alt() { 
    local -i n=$1
    local foo real sys user
    shift
    (($# > 0)) || return;
    { read foo real; read foo user; read foo sys ;} < <(
        { time -p for((;n--;)){ "$@" &>/dev/null ;} ;} 2>&1
    )
    printf "real: %.5f\nuser: %.5f\nsys : %.5f\n" $(
        bc -l <<<"$real/$n;$user/$n;$sys/$n;" )
}
```

**Nota:** This uses `bc` instead of `awk` to compute the average. For this, we would create a temporary `bc` file:

```
printf >/tmp/test-pi.bc "scale=%d;\npi=4*a(1);\nquit\n" 60
```

This would compute *`¶`* with 60 decimals, then exit quietly. (You can adapt number of decimals for your host.)

Demo:

```
avg_time_alt 1000 sleep .001
real: 0.00195
user: 0.00008
sys : 0.00016

avg_time_alt 1000 bc -ql /tmp/test-pi.bc
real: 0.00172
user: 0.00120
sys : 0.00058
```

Where [codeforester's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54920339/1765658) will anser:

```
avg_time 1000 sleep .001
real 0.000000
user 0.000000
sys 0.000000

avg_time 1000 bc -ql /tmp/test-pi.bc
real 0.000000
user 0.000000
sys 0.000000
```

## Alternative, inspired by [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54920334/1765658), using *Linux's*`/proc`

Ok, you could consider:

```
avgByProc() { 
    local foo start end n=$1 e=$1 values times
    shift;
    export n;
    { 
        read foo;
        read foo;
        read foo foo start foo
    } < /proc/timer_list;
    mapfile values < <(
        for((;n--;)){ "$@" &>/dev/null;}
        read -a endstat < /proc/self/stat
        {
            read foo
            read foo
            read foo foo end foo
        } </proc/timer_list
        printf -v times "%s/100/$e;" ${endstat[@]:13:4}
        bc -l <<<"$[end-start]/10^9/$e;$times"
    )
    printf -v fmt "%-7s: %%.5f\\n" real utime stime cutime cstime
    printf "$fmt" ${values[@]}
}
```

This is based on `/proc`:

> ```
> man 5 proc | grep [su]time\\\|timer.list | sed  's/^/>   /'
>             (14) utime  %lu
>             (15) stime  %lu
>             (16) cutime  %ld
>             (17) cstime  %ld
>      /proc/timer_list (since Linux 2.6.21)
> ```

Then now:

```
avgByProc 1000 sleep .001
real   : 0.00242
utime  : 0.00015
stime  : 0.00021
cutime : 0.00082
cstime : 0.00020
```

Where `utime` and `stime` represent *user time* and *system time* for bash himself and `cutime` and `cstime` represent *child user time* and *child system time* **wich are the most interesting**.

**Nota:** In this case (`sleep`) command won't use a lot of ressources.

```
avgByProc 1000 bc -ql /tmp/test-pi.bc
real   : 0.00175
utime  : 0.00015
stime  : 0.00025
cutime : 0.00108
cstime : 0.00032
```

This become more clear...
Of course, as accessing `timer_list` and `self/stat` successively but not *atomicaly*, differences between *`real`* (nanosecs based) and *`c?[su]time`* (based in *ticks* ie: 1/100th sec) may appear!

Comment: Amazing insight!  I like your solution very much.  I agree this is a better approach.  I wish `time -p` had given more precise numbers.

Comment: @codeforester Did you test my alternative, based on `/proc/subShellPid/stat`, showing ***childs** system and user times*?

Comment: For non-English locales (where comma is used instead of the decimal point) `bc` will yield `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` must use something like: `shopt -s expand_aliases; alias bc="sed 's/,/./g' | bc | sed 's/\./,/g'"` and `-l` do not needed, but `scale=5` is recommended in the first example instead of `%.5f` as `bc` will break long lines.

Comment: Aaarg!  `sed | bc | sed` , for each values! You'd better to force `LANG=C bc`!!!

Answer (score 1):

From [bashoneliners](http://www.bashoneliners.com/oneliners/48/)

- adapted to transform (,) to (.) for i18n support
- hardcoded to 10, adapt as needed
- returns only the "real" value, the one you most likely want

Oneliner

```
for i in {1..10}; do time $@; done 2>&1 | grep ^real | sed s/,/./ | sed -e s/.*m// | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum / NR}'
```

I made a "fuller" version

- outputs the results of every execution so you know the right thing is executed
- shows every run time, so you glance for outliers

But really, if you need advanced stuff just use hyperfine.

```
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
RESET='\033[0m'

# example: perf sleep 0.001
# https://serverfault.com/questions/175376/redirect-output-of-time-command-in-unix-into-a-variable-in-bash
perfFull() {
    TIMEFORMAT=%R                       # `time` outputs only a number, not 3 lines
    export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"     # `time` outputs `0.100` instead of local format, like `0,100`

    times=10

    echo -e -n "\nWARMING UP ${PURPLE}$@${RESET}"
    $@ # execute passed parameters

    echo -e -n "RUNNING ${PURPLE}$times times${RESET}"

    exec 3>&1 4>&2                                   # redirects subshell streams
    durations=()
    for _ in `seq $times`; {
        durations+=(`{ time $@ 1>&3 2>&4; } 2>&1`)   # passes stdout through so only `time` is caputured
    }
    exec 3>&- 4>&-                                   # reset subshell streams

    printf '%s\n' "${durations[@]}"

    total=0
    for duration in "${durations[@]}"; {
        total=$(bc <<< "scale=3;$total + $duration")
    }

    average=($(bc <<< "scale=3;$total/$times"))
    echo -e "${GREEN}$average average${RESET}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to record the start and end time of the execution and divide the difference by the number of executions.

```
#!/bin/bash
times=10
start=$(date +%s)
for ((i=0; i < times; i++)) ; do
    run_your_executable_here
done
end=$(date +%s)
bc -l <<< "($end - $start) / $times"
```

I used `bc` to calculate the average, as bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics.

To get more precision, you can switch to nanoseconds:

```
start=$(date +%s.%N)
```

and similarly for `$end`.

Comment: Substituting `+%s` with `'+%s.%N'` throws the error `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: N`.

Comment: @mooncow: Then your `date` is different to mine (GNU 8.25).

Comment: Under recent linux kernel, under **pure bash** you could: `{ read foo;read foo;read foo foo now foo; } </proc/timer_list` without any fork, then `echo $now` wich represent *uptime* in nanoseconds!

Comment: Yes if `/proc/timer_list`'s perms are `-r--r--r-- root root`.

Comment: @choroba U could have a look at my [Alternative, inspired by choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940448/1765658), based on `/proc`.